# Compute squared solutions to a quadratic equation without using sqrt

Tags: math, collision-detection, intersection, quadratic

I am trying to write a circle-to-line-segment collision detection algorithm, which involves determining the intersection point of the circle and the line segment. The line segment represents the trajectory of a bullet over the last frame, which means it would hit the first circle even if there's multiple circles intersecting with the line.

I would like to obtain the `t` value of the point of intersection, which is a measure of how far along the line segment the intersection is. Computing the `t` value requires solving a quadratic equation, which involves the formula `t = (-b - sqrt(det)) / (2 * a)`. To make the code faster, I am trying to avoid using `sqrt` entirely, which means instead of comparing to find the smallest `t` over all potential circles, I will try to find the smallest `t^2` for them. However, I am not sure how to find `t^2` without `sqrt`, even given `t = (-b - sqrt(det)) / (2 * a)`, because the binomial expansion still involves `sqrt`.

How to compute `t^2 = ((-b - sqrt(det)) / (2 * a))^2` without using `sqrt` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to solve

```
(x0 - cx + dx * t)^2 + (y0 - cy + dy * t)^2 = r^2
```

for every `(cx, cy, r)` from a circle set. It is impossible to find `t` value without quadratic equation solution and sqrt in general case.

But perhaps you can (we don't know all problem details) build some space index structure (partition, i.e. kd-tree) to avoid full checking of all these circles.

Comment: I am already using spatial hashing to reduce the number of circles tested. Is there mathematical proof that `t^2` is impossible to obtain?

Comment: Equation contains as t and t^2, it is quadratic equation of general kind. You can check fact of intersection  without sqrt (when line equation is normalized), but it is needed to get point.